# How do I convert an cv::Mat to float pointer?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, memcpy, vlfeat

I want to represent the matrix of `cv::SIFT` descriptors `cv::Mat descriptors` as `float*`. This is because I want to use [GMM from VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/gmm.html) (if you have any better solution, please let me know). This is the code that I came up with:

```
if(!prova.isContinous()){
    std::err<<"Descriptor matrix not continuous!"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
float *data = new float[desc.total()];
std::memcpy(data,prova.data,prova.total() * sizeof(float));
```

Trying this code with a toy matrix:

```
cv::Mat prova = (cv::Mat_<float>(3,3) << 0.1, 0.3, 2.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8);
```

And print the values:

```
for(int i=0;i<prova.total();i++)
    std::cout<<*(data+i)<<std::endl;
```

This works fine, but since we're dealing with pointers (and it's always a dangerous matter) I would like an opinion.

**NOTE:** just for giving a context, this is how I'm going to use `data`:

```
VlGMM* gmm = vl_gmm_new(VL_TYPE_FLOAT, desc.cols, 2) ;
vl_gmm_cluster (gmm, data, desc.rows);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Mat::ptr` method to get the float pointer to the beginning of any row.  Specifically, the beginning of the matrix is:

```
const float* buffer=desc_mat.ptr<float>(0);
```

Comment: That was tricky :) But then I'm not sure if it's safe to give to `gmm` simply `buffer` instead of data. I'm still unexpert with `VLFeat`.

Comment: @Photon  To get the whole data, I usually just write `float* imageData = (float*)image.data;`

Comment: Two issues: I try to avoid C style casting, which may lead to invalid conversions sometime.  Using knowledge of the implementation which may change one day is usually less robust than using the interface.

Answer (score -1):

the issue that can happen if stride not equal to number of columns*4
4= size of float, you can get holes in the data so the only way to be sure is to copy pixel by pixel